# Sending props with flux-react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, flux

I'm currently using flux-react-router npm with my reactApp,
and I'm having issues routing to the url + sending a prop to the component.

This is how I route to the url:
onClick={()=>{ReactRouter.goTo(`productpage/${item._id}`)}}

http://localhost:3000/productpage/5cb82c114e1efafcd06dc159

The url does work, but the prop is undefined until I reload the page and rerender the component.

I currently use window.location.href.split('/') to get the ID but i would like to pass it as a prop but it seems to only catch the prop when i rerender the component not when i route to it.

here's my component in index.js

```js
Flux.createRoute('/productpage/{id}',function(params){
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(document.getElementById('root'));
    ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}><ProductPage id={params.id}/></PersistGate></Provider>,document.getElementById('root'));
})
```

I just want it to send the prop while routing instead of reloading the page to catch the prop.

Comment: Please upload your code in text format, rather than a picture

Comment: Edited the post

Comment: Still need help :/